# R: Memory Allocation on Ubuntu for R vs Rscript

Tags: r, ubuntu, memory-management, out-of-memory, rscript

I have created a script, and when I run it line-by-line on Ubuntu, everything works from end-to-end, however, when I run it using Rscript it fails due to a memory allocation error.

I have tried to remove excess variables using **rm** followed by **gc**, and I have tried to run the code using **R CMD BATCH**, but nothing seems to work.

Does anyone know why memory allocation is different between running **R** and **Rscript**?

Sorry, I cannot really do a reproducible example for this problem due to the sensible data, but the packages I use are **RJDBC** with the setting **options(java.parameters = "-Xmx8g")** on a computer with 16 Gb of RAM, and I also use the **parallel**-package, which is where the error occurs.